# How to display exception details on a page?

Tags: orchardcms

Instead of "Oops. Something went wrong ... sorry. An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back"

When an exception happens I want to display the error message and stack trace on the page. How can I do that? On my local dev machine, I want to be able to see the full error details.

Thanks.

Comment: Dud U set the error page in ur web config?

Comment: Nvm. I was able to do Model.Message, Model.Exception.StackTrace in ErrorPage.cshtml under Core/Shapes/Views

Answer (score 1):

Look at app_data\logs. The full details should be there.

Comment: That's what I usually do. But I wanted to save few clicks, and see the exception details right there on the page.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do that, but you should be able to do it by overriding ErrorPage.cshtml.